# How to connect nested xpaths for Selenium webdriver assert? i.e. Label and separate button in a row

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to assert that a button on our page is disabled. The below HTML is what I am working with at the moment:

```
<div data-persona-noeditable="" style="display: block;">
    <div class="c-potential-tooltip persona-name pull-left" data-potential-tooltip="">
        <div data-name-persona="" class="marg5" data-original-title="" title="">autoTestMapped</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-small pull-left marg5" data-copy-persona="">Copy</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small pull-left marg5" data-edit-persona="" style="display: inline-block;">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small pull-left marg5" data-persona-deactivate="" disabled="" style="display: inline-block;">Deactivate</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small pull-left marg5" data-persona-activate="" style="display: none;">Activate</button>
    <i class="fa fa-times pull-down" data-persona-delete="" style="display: none;"></i>
</div>
```

I am attempting to check if the Deactivate button is disabled or not, but I want to tie it together with label name in the row, `autoTestMapped`.

This is nested in the first div and I am having trouble figuring out how to get Selenium to look at both of them to confirm the button goes with that specific user.

I have tried different variations on:

```
Assert.assertFalse("deactivate button is disabled for autoTestMapped", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*div[contains(text(), 'autoTestMapped')]")).isEnabled());
```

including using | to connect the two separate XPaths, but nothing seems to work. I can hardcode the xpath location, but this isn't static as a newly created user might cause the list to move up or down.

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) would be helpful here:

```
//div[contains(@class, "persona-name") and div = "autoTestMapped"]/following-sibling::button[. = "Deactivate"]
```